# Declare a function in a class

Tags: typescript

How do you declare a function in a class like so

```
FooVariable = function FooFunction(FooMethod) {
}
```

I'm trying to do it this way instead of FooFunction(FooMethod) so that FooFunction doesn't end up in the prototype..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want an instance method like this:

```
class Foo {
    fooFunction() {

    }
}
```

You can add the static keyword:

```
class Foo {
    static fooFunction() {

    }
}
```

The resulting JavaScript is:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() { }
    Foo.fooFunction = function fooFunction() {
    };
    return Foo;
})();
```

Comment: Cool, what will the context of **this** be in fooFunction?

Comment: It depends where you call it from. If you bound it to an event, it would be the event target. As it is static, `this` wouldn't represent an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: I see, so how do I declare an instance function in a ts class, but forcing it not to be assigned to the prototype?ie a function like AppVersion -#>  ViewModel(jsonModel) {
    self.AppVersion = function (result) {